# how to create arrow CSS like shown below from a point to b point with lines going to each node in between.?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[need this sort of pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz61S.png)

My Implementation is below but i am confused how to add the nodes and end div exactly below the line.

```css
.point {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(177, 207, 219, 1);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.point:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 2px;
  background: black;
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="point">Start</div>
```

Comment: Check out https://gojs.net/latest/ for this kind of stuff

Comment: need more flexible approach